# iOS System message (e.g. hotspot) on top blocking my app - how to get notified?

Tags: ios, swift

iOS System message (e.g. hotspot) on top blocking my app. For example when there is a hotspot connection message on top (see attached) the view is blocked. Facebook knows this and makes it's view smaller.

Can I setup a notification for this in my app, so that I can change the view somehow?

using: Xcode 7.2, Swift 2, need it for iOS 8.4 and above.

[image: Screen view of the iOS message]

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: I suggest looking into autolayout. Things spaced from the top layout guide should adjust automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- use auto-layout and always use constraints to the top layout guide (recommended)
- add the `application:didChangeStatusBarFrame:` method to your app delegate (and somehow pass it down to view controllers, etc.)
- listen for `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` notifications